# PowerShell Tee-object command doesn't work on git pull

Tags: command-line, powershell, git

The following powershell command works as expected:

```
get-process | tee-object -filepath C:\Test1\testfile2.txt
```

But if I change it to:

```
git pull | tee-object -filepath C:\Test1\testfile2.txt
```

I see the git pull command execute normally but C:\Test1\testfile2.txt still has the output from get-process.

Any idea why?

Comment: git pull |gm   
....................

Comment: gm   Enumerate the properties of an object ?

Comment: I see: 

`gm : You must specify an object for the Get-Member cmdlet.
At line:1 char:12
+ git pull | gm
+            ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-Member], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoObjectInGetMember,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetMemberCommand`

Comment: git isn't a cmdlet and so doesn't expose objects to the pipeline. Normal output from .exe programs to standardout should be piped and handled properly by `Tee-Object`. Maybe git output is to stderror, so try  `git pull 2>&1 | tee-object -filepath C:\Test1\testfile2.txt`

Comment: That worked, can you explain what the 2>&1 part does?

Comment: @Eric , I was in a hurry, sorry. yeah, gm or Get-Member gives you the type, properties and methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In cmd.exe there are two output streams, stdoutput and stderroroutput
  numbered 1 and 2.
- Batch/console prepends 1 to a redirection `>` if not a different
  stream number is supplied manually.
- Looks like git outputs to stderroroutput, so 2>&1 merges
  stderroroutput(2) with stdoutput(1) so it is piped and tee is able to
  echo and store to the file.
- In powershell there are additional streams, see [powershell streams](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/)